# WAMP + PHP in CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface, wamp

can somebody tell me how to solve the problem with WAMP and PHP in console on Windows 10? Windows use PATH variable to find the path to php.exe. It is necessary(or not?) to run php in console. But if PHP is in PATH variable WAMP throws me an error about PHP is in the PATH. But I need to use PHP in browser and also in console. How can I do it? Thanks.